# 3D Visualization in 3D

Tags: arcgis-server, 3d-analyst, geoprocessing-service, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

We have published a geoprocessing tool that gives Raster dataset as output. we are using arcgis javascript api 4.0 version to visualize it on map. But when we use gp.getResultImageLayer , the event returns MapImageLayer. Now, we want to apply elevations to this MapImageLayer. This layer can be generated dynamically based on the input ascii file which we give input to the Geoprocessing tool.

Is it possible to apply elevation to MapImageLayer?